# zend framework 2 form umlaut

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm working on a projekt wir zf2. In my ProductForm.php I've some umlauts like 'ü' and 'ö'.
In the browser they look like 'H�chstbestellmenge:'. 
Here is a part of my ProductForm.php:

```
...

$this->add(array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
                'name' => 'status',
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Status:',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'value_options' => array(
                                '1' => 'verfügbar',
                                '2' => 'ausverkauft'
                        ),
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                        'value' => '1' 

                )
        ));
...

$this->add(array(
                'name' => 'maxOrderQuantity',
                'attributes' => array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'id' => 'maxOrderQuantity',
                ),
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Höchstbestellmenge:'
                ),
        ));

...
```

Can someone help me to change this?
Tanks.

Answer (score 2):

This problem shouldn't related with ZF2. You have to set default character set of your http server to render utf-8 characters in browser(s) properly.

For apache, add the line below to httpd.conf:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

For nginx, add similar charset definition to `http` block in `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    charset utf-8;
    // ...
}
```

You can also try to use `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following between your 
 tags in the layout.phtml file in layout folder

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```